# Returning response to controller from factory method in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory called Auth with a method `Auth.signIn()` that authenticates through my decoupled API. That part works, and I'm trying to capture the response which is the User information. Calling the factory from my controller works, but I can't seem to capture the response of the method.

**controller**

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, Auth) {
  //OAUTH SIGN IN
  $scope.signIn = function() {
    $scope.currentUser = Auth.signIn()
    //^^Auth.signIn() is happening but $scope.currentUser is undefined when I try to access it in the view
  }
  //OAUTH SIGN OUT
  $scope.signOut = function() {
    Auth.signOut()
  }

})
```

**factory**

```
.factory('Auth', function($auth) {
  var user = null
  return {
    signIn: function() {
      $auth.authenticate('google')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response //trying to catch this in the controller with currentUser = Auth.signIn()
        //verified that response is the user data
      })
      .catch(function(resp) {
        // handle errors
      })
    }
})
```

I'm new to angular so any help and pointers would be appreciated. I'm trying to be as concise as possible with my code/questions. Thank you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in your factory's signIn function, you should return the promise

```
signIn: function() {
      return $auth.authenticate('google')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      });
    }
```

Then in your controller, chain the `currentUser` initialization after `Auth.signIn`

```
$scope.signIn = function() {
    Auth.signIn().then(function(data) {
      $scope.currentUser = data;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. As I mentioned in the other comment I grasp this deferred promises concept, but working around that in my code is still new. I'm going to test this out now.

Comment: Personally I prefer promise chain, which is more common and easier to understand than callbacks.

Comment: I'm using {{currentUser.name}} in the view, but it's not resolving to anything. Is that because the view is rendering before currentUser.name is resolved?

Comment: `$scope.currentUser` is initialized only after `signIn` function is called. you can hide it by `<div ng-if="currentUser">{{currentUser.name}}</div>`, then it won't show until it's initialized.

Comment: THANK YOU. FWIW mentioning, in the factory it's just ```response``` instead of ```response.data``` but that's just depended on my specific api's return . Live in the Bay Area by chance? I'll buy you a beer. I spent way too long in this rabbit hole.

Comment: Great to know it's solved now. Currently I live in China but I'm planning to move to Bay Area later this year. Maybe we can have a drink when I finally make it.